# Show Volume Level OSD on both monitors?

Tags: windows, audio, user-interface, osd

I use my main monitor often for games and external sources but I have all my audio running through my PC via audio in. I'd like to be able to see the volume indicator (default that shows up in the top left) on my second monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I know I'm a little late to the party but I just had to answer this. I use a third party program called 3RVX that allows you to customise the volume OSD entirely and show volume controls over fullscreen apps as well. It also allows you to display the OSD on multiple monitor or even a single monitor of your choice.

Here's a link to their website:
https://3rvx.com/